# Android setVisibility to GONE in a View part of a DialogFragment which implements OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, view, keyevent, onitemclicklistener, dialogfragment

I have a class that extends extends DialogFragment and implements OnItemClickListener.

In this DialogFragment I have a view called rootView, where I inflate my main view. When I press a button, I create two views:

```
    selectItemForm = rootView.findViewById(R.id.logging_selectitem_form);
    portionForm = rootView.findViewById(R.id.logging_selectitem_portion);
    //switch forms
    selectItemForm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    portionForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Thus, there is the following view sequence rootView > selectItemForm > portionForm .

However, when I press the BACK button in portionForm I return to rootView rather than to selectItemForm.

I also created a key listener as follows:

```
portionForm.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.v(TAG + "_setPortionFormOnKeyListener", "I have clicked on the BACK button.");
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

                    //switch forms
                    if(portionForm.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        portionForm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        selectItemForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        return true; 
                    } 
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

However, this KeyListener is never called, so it is not working either.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp( int keyCode, KeyEvent event )
{
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK )
    {
       if(portionForm.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        portionForm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        selectItemForm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
    return super.onKeyUp( keyCode, event );
}
```

Comment: I cannot use the designated method, since my class extends DialogFragment and OnItemClickListener, and this method is only applicable for extends Activity.

Comment: When I attach setOnKeyListener to my portionForm, the method onKey(..) is never called. I tried with another key and in debug mode, and the onKey is never called. Any idea why the the OnKeyListener is not called?